# Windows 10 File Explorer - Prevent FTP Connection From Opening In New Window

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, ftp

I'm using Windows 10 Professional v20H2.  I set up a new FTP network connection in File Explorer.  When I click on the connection, it opens the list of files and folders on the FTP server in a new window.  What I'd like to happen is to have the folder view shown beneath the connection instead of opening a new window.

Is this possible?  If so, how do I configure Windows 10 to make this happen?

Comment: Is the list of files and folders in Quick Access?  Right click on Quick Access, select Options and then lower right, Clear Quick Access. That may help.

Comment: In Folder Options, General tab, have you by any chance unset the option of "Open each folder in the same window"? Or in the View tab, have you set "Launch folder windows in a separate process"?

Comment: I did try unselecting the "Open each folder in the same window" option.  No change.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ftp server name instead of its IP address.

My original configuration of the File Explorer FTP network connection used the IP address of the FTP server.  I checked the properties of the connection and, instead of showing the IP address I had used to create the connection, it showed the name of the FTP server.  On a hunch I deleted the connection and re-created it using the FTP server name instead of its IP address.  Everything now works as expected - I see a complete list of folders and files when I click on the connection - WITHOUT OPENING A NEW WINDOW.